# Update Git remote : object directory

Tags: git, repo

I need some help.. how can I update git repository in remote after doing this cleanup?

In local my `.git` directory, size is 1.7GB only, and in remote I have 40GB size. How can I update the remote to make it 1.7GB, same as in my local? One thing that makes 40GB is the object directory in `.git`, I clean it up in my local and now it is now 1.7GB, how can I push this update?

I used this command to clean up:

```
 git gc --aggressive --prune
```

Comment: @DanLowe i just use this command git gc --aggressive --prune

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `git gc` command performs garbage collection on the local repository only. This is not something you can push to a remote.

If you are in control of the remote, you can perform a garbage collection on it as well. How exactly to do that really depends on the software you are using (e.g. gitolite, Gitlab, Bitbucket...)

If you are using a service such as Github, they take care of this automatically themselves, you don't need to do anything.

Comment: ah i see.. im using gitlab in my own server, so I just run git gc --aggressive --prune in my gitlab server driectly to make this changes

Comment: Gitlab normally does this stuff on its own, you don't need to do anything. If you look in the admin settings, under "Automatic Git repository housekeeping", you'll see it likely has automatic repository housekeeping enabled already. If not, that's where you can turn it on.

Comment: ah .. I already saw it and it is enable.
what value can you suggest for this sir? 
Incremental repack period : current is 10,
Full repack period : current is 50,
Git GC period currrent is 200

Comment: @rkevx21 I left my settings at the defaults, I saw no reason to change them.